# [laravel]dropdown not working inside @guest

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I work on laravel project

the dropdown not working inside `@guest` but works outside it, tried many solutions but once I put the same code outside `@guest @endguest` it worked like it should.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
    <!-- Authentication Links -->
    @guest
        @if (Route::has('login'))
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link button btn" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
        </li>
        @endif

        @if (Route::has('register'))
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link button btn" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
        </li>
        @endif
        @else
        <li class=" dropdown nav-item">
            <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  role="button"
               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >
                {{ Auth::user()->name }}
            </a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                   document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                    {{ __('Logout') }}
                </a>

                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                    @csrf
                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
    @endguest
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there any errors in the console tab?

Comment: What about those `@endif @else`?

Comment: you have `@endif` but no `@if`

Comment: there  is no errors
please see the full code i edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not used correctly `@if @else` statements, because you ended **if** with `@endif` and started `@else` after ending **if**.

This should work for you

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
    <!-- Authentication Links -->
    @guest
        @if (Route::has('login'))
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link button btn" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
        </li>    
        @elseif (Route::has('register'))
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link button btn" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
        </li>
        @else
        <li class=" dropdown nav-item">
            <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  role="button"
               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >
                {{ Auth::user()->name }}
            </a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                   document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                    {{ __('Logout') }}
                </a>

                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                    @csrf
                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
        @endif
    @endguest
</ul>
```